# Wijmo 5 - Flexgrid & AngularJS - using same data source for other in scope directives

Tags: angularjs, wijmo, wijgrid

Trying out the new Flex grid from Wijimo 5 along with AngularJS.

My app loads data via a HTTP call and the Grid is bound to a controller level object as its data source.  If I just do a standard Angular HTTP call and set the object then the Grid does not display the data until I click on the column headers.

So something like this:

```
<body  ng-controller="LimoController as limo">
<wj-flex-grid items-source="limo.limoData" show-groups="false" >
        <wj-flex-grid-column
                header="Status"
                binding="booking.status"
                width="*"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        <wj-flex-grid-column
                header="Pickup Date"
                binding="from.date"
                format="d MMMM"
                width="*"></wj-flex-grid-column>
    </wj-flex-grid>
```

and then within the app.js I have a factory to get the data but ultimately within the controller I have:

```
limo.limoData =results
```

I also have a ng-repeat directive which is creating some additional form UI which is also bound to the same data (this data is editable), this works fine as its standard AngularJS stuff.

I then tried changing the results object to a CollectionView - like this:

```
limo.limoData =new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(results);
```

This fixed the Grid displaying the data immediately but broke the ng-repeat control.

I could of course have 2 scope objects, 1 as a CollectionView the other as standard data but I need the editable updates from the ng-repeat to be reflected in the grid so ideally they need to be bound to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is bind your ng-repeat to the 'items' property of your CollectionView. Here is an example of doing that.

http://jsfiddle.net/1r4ebc33/1/

Your code might look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in limo.limoData.items">
     {{booking.status}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Glad it works. Sounds like we could use this in our docs... ;)

Comment: My original answer proposed the use of CollectionView.sourceCollection. I have revised it to recommend CollectionView.items. The items will reflect the sorted/filtered view of data, whereas the sourceCollection will be the raw data.